# Pipeline Stall Related to BNE Execution and Label Instruction Fetch

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

Below is the solution related to a pipeline question.

[image]

After reading the solution, I have a question.

Why the first line `bne $7, $0, L1` **EX** is at same cycle for the **IF** of last line `L1:sw $8, 0($3)`? For my understanding, before instruction fetch for the last line, it should wait until `bne` finish executing the condition and knowing if it needs to fetch instruction or not.

Any hint appreciates. Thanks so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#Control_hazards, **classic MIPS resolves branches in the ID stage**, and the branch-delay slot completely hides the front-end bubble.  (Assuming the compiler can fill it with something other than a NOP).

---

**Even if that wasn't true and the branch did need to wait for EX to be resolved**, the CPU can speculatively fetch and decode the later instructions; none of them reach MEM or WB before the correct branch direction is detected so they have no permanent effect on the architectural state.  (In fact none of them even reach EX, so there's no speculative execution at all, just speculative decode).

If EX detected that the branch should have been taken, then the pipeline would have to restart fetch of the `sw` instruction without the `jr` in the pipe.  (The `add` stays because it's in the branch-delay slot: it's executed in both cases.)

Further reading: [difference between speculation and prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930178/difference-between-speculation-and-prediction), and also this unclearly-worded question [Out-of-order execution vs. speculative execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49601910/out-of-order-execution-vs-speculative-execution).  Hadi's nice answer covers a range of things CPUs can do before they're sure which way a branch goes.

Simply fetching and decoding instructions based on branch prediction, but not executing them, is one of the easier ones, and many people don't consider it speculative *execution* at all.  It is still speculation that requires a pipeline flush / re-steer, unlike stalling until the correct fetch address is known for sure.  (Without a branch delay slot, you couldn't even detect a branch (in decode) until you've already fetched an instruction from potentially the wrong path.  In deeper / wider pipelines, branch prediction is important for predicting the next fetch-block address even before decode has figured out if there *are* any branches in the current block.  This is separate from a detailed prediction of where a specific branch instruction goes.)

---

**The weird thing with this diagram is that it shows `jr` and `sw` in the same stage in the same cycle**.  That makes no sense, and the `sw` can't stall before fetch even reaches it.

Is this for a taken-branch case?  That wouldn't make sense either, because then `jr` shouldn't be in the pipeline at all.  And `sw` can't stall on the same cycle where `add` is in the fetch stage.

Comment: Well, my answer says that branch prediction is only one form of speculative execution. [Wkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) agrees with me on this definition. Both old and recent research papers and textbooks use the term in the broad sense like I did in the answer. Although some articles and papers do use the term to specifically refer to executing instructions speculatively. However, speculatively fetching instructions is generally considered to be some form of speculative execution. So such works are classified under that area.

Comment: Remember that instruction fetching is the first stage of the pipeline, and to execute an instruction, it really has to go through all the stages of the pipeline. When an instruction is said to have completed execution, it means that it has passed all stages of the pipeline, not just the EXE stage.

Comment: @HadiBrais: hmm, is that the accepted terminology?  I thought part of the important thing with spec-exec was potentially starting an expensive operation (like a multiply, or a cache-miss load) from the wrong path.  Or an operation that would fault if it wasn't in the shadow of a mispredict.  Handling that seems like an important part of what's difficult.

Comment: Effectively, that "stall" label makes no sense. If they considered no delay-slot, the `add` ought to be stalled too. If they did the `sw` could not be fetched but after the `add`.  Maybe they used, as a reference, an ideal CPU  that resolves branches in the IF stage.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I wondered if it was a formatting error; it would be less insane if the `sw` row was shifted to the right by 1 cycle.  But that's still not a clear explanation.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help. So much appreciate.